# How to assign a colormap to a matplotlib graph animation?

Tags: matplotlib, animation, colors, viridis

I have animated a two-dimensional line, and I want it to display in the viridis colormap.  The code is not working, because I am unsure of where in the code to assign the colormap, and how exactly to define it.

I have tried defining 'viridis' and calling it in various places, including within the defined function 'LineAnimation' and outside it, and within the 'animate' function of 'LineAnimation'.  Currently the code looks like this:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
from collections import OrderedDict
viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 12)

def LineAnimation(Song,Times):

    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, len(song)), ylim=(-np.amax(song), np.amax(song)))
    #ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)


    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    def animate(i):
        x = times[:i]
        y = song[:i]
        line.set_data(x, y)
        line.register_cmap(name='viridis', cmap=viridis)
        line.set_cmap(viridis)

        return line,

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, init_func=init,
                                   frames=len(song), interval=20, blit=True)

    plt.show()
    return anim
```

I expect to see the animation in the viridis color bar: starting at purple and ending at yellow.  But I get no output or error message.

Comment: You cannot assign a colormap to a `plot`. Instead you will need to use a `LineCollection`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856091/4124317) on how to create such collection with a colormap.