# How to generate the lineared color plot (cplot) with z values in colorbar

Tags: python, plot, idl-programming-language

In MATLAB™ one can use [`cplot.m`](http://pordlabs.ucsd.edu/matlab/graph7.htm) which can generate colored plot basically looks like 2d plot with 3rd axis (z-axis) value as colorbar. Is there any tool/plotting technique I can use to generate a similar plot in Python or IDL Programming Language?. The previous question on stack overflow dealing with different problem as given in a link.

[image: cplot image (Linear colored line plot]

Comment: What do you mean with "lineared" ??

Comment: The duplicate does not address the IDL part of the question. See http://www.idlcoyote.com/graphics_tips/coloredline.html for an example solution (use `plots` or `cgplots` if you have the Coyote library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDL v8 has an easy to use keyword for the PLOT function called [VERT_COLORS](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/PLOT.html#VERT_COL):

```
; generate some sample data
x = cos(dindgen(100)/20)
y = sin(dindgen(100)/20)
z = dindgen(100)+100

; plot the data
p = plot(x, y, vert_colors=bytscl(z), rgb_table=39, xrange=[-2,2], yrange=[-2,2], thick=3, /aspect_ratio)
cb = colorbar(range=[min(z), max(z)], target=p)
```

[image: plot with colorbar]

The z data is scaled to a byte index of the colortable number 39. The colorbar needs to know the data range explicitly.

Comment: The colorbar should show me the values on the z-axis. but it showing else h=colorbar(p). any idea on bringing z-axis value on the colorbar.

Comment: I updated the example in the post above to include a colorbar.

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib has not a `cplot` direct equivalent but you can use a `LineCollection`.

With this understanding you have to modify the usual boilerplate adding a specific import

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   ...: from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
```

Now, generate some data (`c` is the 3rd value associated with the `(x, y)` point)

```
In [2]: x = np.linspace(0, 6.3, 64) 
   ...: y = np.sin(x) ; c = np.cos(x)
```

`LineCollection` needs a 3D array, i.e. a list of segments, each segment a list of points, each point a list of coordinates, that we build using this [recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880037/2749397)

```
In [3]: points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2) 
   ...: segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
```

Now we instantiate the `LineCollection`, specifying the colormap that we want and the line width, and immediately after we tell to our instance that its `array` (what is mapped to colors) is the array `c`

```
In [4]: lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='plasma', linewidth=3) 
   ...: lc.set_array(c)
```

and eventually we plot `lc` in its own way, call `autoscale` because it's needed (try not to call it...) and add a colorbar.

```
In [5]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()                                                          
   ...: ax.add_collection(lc) 
   ...: ax.autoscale() 
   ...: plt.colorbar(lc);
```

[image]

I know, it's a bit clunky but it works.